# M2 - Weird coupon date change on save

Tags: magento2.3, coupon, coupon-codes, date

Magento version: 2.3.4

When I create a new shopping cart price rule (coupon code) and choose a date range like this:

[image]

Then in the coupon overview list I see this date:

[image]

So that correct, but when I open the coupon code to edit I see this date range:

[image]

I have no idea where this is coming from... Anyone a idea?